# Texlive-math-extra and texlive-latex-extra packages cannot be installed

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, linux

I am using Fedora 19, TexMaker and TeX Live.
When I tried to compile my .tex document, I got the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `stmaryrd.sty' not found

I found out that the file is a part of `texlive-math-extra` package.
When I tried to install the package using the command

```
yum install texlive-math-extra
```

I get the following response:

> No package texlive-math-extra available

Could anyone, please, tell me, how I can install the package? Or what might be the problem with my way of installation

P.S. I have the same story with `texlive-latex-extra package`
P.S. Just copying the required .sty files to `home/texmf/tex` directory does not help me because I also need some other files from the packages

Comment: Do you need root privileges to install?

Comment: [Fedora (18) TexLive (2012)](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive): `texlive-collection-mathextra` Did you mispell?

Comment: Well, in all honesty, just install the TeXlive from TeX's official sources and not from Fedora's ones. You'll save yourself a lot of troubles like this one. The way how TeXlive gets into the distros is very unfortunate. Useful link: http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Answer (score 6):

It seems that in 2018 the package is now called `texlive-science`.

Answer (score 4):

The fedora package is called `texlive-collection-mathextra`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the help! I Have found the solution. The command for the installation is just

`yum install stmaryrd` and `yum install subfigure` (for my second issue).

Texlive-mathextra indeed contains stmaryrd.sty (I saw it) as it is suggested here: http://gentoo.2317880.n4.nabble.com/which-package-contains-latex-stmaryrd-sty-td139586.html and here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1040608.html. But all the forums where they suggest to install this package are dedicated to Ubuntu while I have Fedora. Probably, that was the reason.